# Why are locks said to violate the principles of abstraction and composability?

Tags: abstraction, locks, system-design

I failed to find any definite answer on Google or even StackOverflow to answer this question.

From my understanding

- Threads that use locks can break abstraction
- Locks are not composable

But how and why does a lock break abstraction and composability?

Comment: From my understanding...

Locks don't compose. A composable system should provide components that can be selected and assembled in any order to meet a specific requirement.

Comment: Hope someone with experience and/or understanding of system design and parallelism through threads can answer this for me.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: I think locks are Singletons, so perhaps looking up the Singleton pattern can give you the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no, that did not help me try to understand how a lock is said the violate the principles of abstraction and composability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert and I couldn't find anything online either. I'm probably doing the same subject as you at uni and here's what I came up with (speaking from personal experience).

The issue locks pose to the principle of abstraction is that the state of a lock and its resources may not be determinable by the state of the currently executing instruction set. For example, in C++ you could have a Baker class, that requires mutually-exclusive access to some Oven object. The Baker needs to use the oven quite often (open/close/put things inside) and requires exclusive access to an Oven to do so, however this cannot be truly abstracted as when exactly he requires this mutually-exclusive access may matter to his function.

We may need to add functionality to our system that is separate to the Baker, but requires mutually-exclusive access to the same Oven the baker is using. In implementing these changes, due to how locks depend on the state of multiple threads at once, we are not assured that the behaviour of the previously-abstracted Baker class will remain the same in the runtime of our programs. (EG: If the oven is being used by another thread, the baker might decide to wait 30 minutes before checking to see if the Oven is free again, which may be unwanted, inefficient behaviour).

Due to the same issues, locks also violate the principles of composability as different components of a program cannot be seamlessly composed if they all depend on each other’s potentially undefined behavior in a multi-threaded application.

Hope that helps - let me know your thoughts so we can ace this together.

Comment: Yeah I'm fairly certain we are both doing CAB401 :P I just discussed this with a few people today and came to the same conclusion. Abstraction was a very interesting discussion. Thanks bud. :)

Answer (score 0):

Informally, composability means to take two or more functional programs and make a bigger program out of them. Composition should be based on published interfaces and not knowing internal details.

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)#cite_note-5. In this example, the transfer method cannot be written correctly without knowing the locking protocol(implementation detail of the account class)